# Performance issue with Tableau - Datastax ODBC - apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, odbc, tableau-api, datastax

I created an employee table in `Cassandra` (3.0.9) with the following details:

```
 empid | empname   | empsal
-------+-----------+--------
 5     | employee5 |   5000
 1     | employee1 |   1000
 2     | employee2 |   2000
 4     | employee4 |   4000
 3     | employee3 |   3000
```

After that, I created a report in `tableau` with a simple bar chart and published the report.

Refresh on the report takes nearly 20 secs. 
Just insert another row to the table, and refresh the report. It takes 20 secs again to load the report.

**Note: whether we load additional data or not, a simple refresh in the report takes nearly 20 secs.**

`Tableau` server and database are in same network in aws. We did check out with different network but in the same region.
There is no difference in terms of performance.

We are using `Datastax ODBC connector` for the connection between `tableau` and `cassandra`.
Is there anything we can do to improve the performance ?

Comment: What are number of rows and exact queries?

Comment: Number of rows: 3
select * from emp;